# UISwipeGestureRecognizer not working for swipe right

Tags: ios, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm working on an iOS app that's programmed in Swift and for some reason my app is unable to recognize/handle the swipe right gesture. Here is my code:

```
self.feedTableViewCell.productPreview.userInteractionEnabled = true
var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("respondToSwipeGesture:"))
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
self.feedTableViewCell.productPreview.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("respondToSwipeGesture:"))
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
self.feedTableViewCell.productPreview.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

And here's my handler:

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(swipeGesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    switch swipeGesture.direction {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
        println("swipe left")
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
        println("swipe right")
    default:
        println("Unknown gesture")
        break
    }

    self.feedTableViewCell.pageControl.currentPage = self.currentFeedImage
}
```

I'm able to swipe to the left fine, but when I swipe right, the app crashes and I get an (lldp) error. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try placing a breakpoint within your handler function? On which line does the app crash?

Comment: I see no issue in the code above. check if there is any issue with your pageControl

Comment: Go through this code you will able to sort your self 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583903/how-to-implement-swipe-left-and-swipe-right-to-reveal-different-kind-of-labels