# How to implement swipe left and swipe right to reveal different kind of labels

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I want to implement swipe left and swipe right to reveal different set of labels. So far I was able to implement following but how to implement swipe to right to reveal some labels.

Since the code is very long and considering the @shamas-s and @ducky suggestion I have upload a sample project to the github.

The github link : https://github.com/ankahathara/SwipToRightAndLeft

This works fine when user swipe for left. It will reveal the label  which is on the right side of the view. But when user swipe right it will set to default. Since I am having a UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right in table view cell I do not understand anyway to revel some other labels when user swiping to right.

Any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: Right now the question has a huge chunk of code. If you shorten it somehow, I'm sure you'll receive more help.

Comment: If you could share your code on GitHub, you would get the answer very quickly :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will upload them to the Github ...